# I there any way to get/change the parameter values just before a method is invoked?

Tags: java, methods, reflection

I have a Class , in which there are 50+ methods. Now I want to do some process to all the parameters in this 50+ methods when the method is called. One way to do is call your process method in each of the methods.

My Question is like, I have a class A

with methods

b c d and e

if c is called from somewhere ,

is there any way to get the parameter values before it reaches c.

Eg:

```
class A{

    public void hello(String message){
        // code
    }

    public void superMethod(Method method){
        //this method is invoked before any method call in class A
        //you can manipulate parameters and its values.
    }

}
```

is there anything like the above given `superMethod` ?

I am sorry if this is a foolish Question.

Comment: Search in google as `Java AOP - AspectJ`

Comment: Specifically, AspectJ is designed to do exactly this.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response , I'll do some research with Java AOP and AspectJ.

Comment: As an aside, AOP can be a code smell (and a maintenance headache) if used improperly.  Tread lightly if you are not an expert.